# NCCL error when using Sagemaker distributed training without specifying a distribution strategy (custom distributed setup)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

When launching two `ml.g4dn.12xlarge` instances without specifying the distribution parameter in the job launcher, followed by reading the resourceConfig.json file, and using the `nccl` backend for torch.distributed.init_process_group, I am unable to broadcast a tensor with the error

```
libfabric:164:1673312506:efa:cq:rxr_cq_write_tx_error():243<warn> rxr_cq_write_tx_error: err: 21, prov_err: Unknown error -21 (21)
algo-1:164:225 [0] ofi_process_cq:1033 NCCL WARN NET/OFI Request 0x7f4a6c335028 completed with error. RC: 21. Error: unknown error. Completed length: 0, Request: { buffer_index: 255, dev: 0, size: 0, state: CREATED, direction: SEND }
```

entrypoint.py

```
import json
import os

import boto3

SRC_DIR_COPY_PATH = "/opt/ml/code"
DOWNLOAD_PATH = "/opt/ml/data"
os.makedirs(DOWNLOAD_PATH, exist_ok=True)


def train():
    training_env = json.loads(os.environ['SM_TRAINING_ENV'])
    hosts = training_env['hosts']
    curr_host = training_env['current_host']
    node_index = hosts.index(curr_host)
    num_hosts = len(hosts)
    master_addr = '127.0.0.1'
    master_port = 29500
    flags = ""
    if num_hosts > 1:
        print('using multi-instance distributed training')
        master_addr = os.environ.get('MASTER_ADDR')
        master_port = os.environ.get('MASTER_PORT')
        nccl_socket_ifname = os.environ.get('NCCL_SOCKET_IFNAME')
        print(f'{nccl_socket_ifname=}')
        flags = f'NCCL_SOCKET_IFNAME={nccl_socket_ifname} FI_PROVIDER="efa" FI_HMEM=0 FI_EFA_USE_DEVICE_RDMA=0 NCCL_DEBUG=INFO FI_LOG_LEVEL=warn FI_LOG_PROV=efa'

    print(f'{master_addr=} {master_port=}')

    PYTHONPATH = os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH')
    num_gpus = 1  # just test with one gpu for now
    print(f'{num_gpus=} {hosts=}, {curr_host=} {node_index=} {num_hosts=}')

    cmd = f'PYTHONPATH={PYTHONPATH} python -m torch.distributed.launch \
              --nnodes={num_hosts} \
              --node_rank={node_index} \
              --master_addr={master_addr} \
              --nproc_per_node={num_gpus} \
              --master_port={master_port} \
              /opt/ml/code/train2.py'

    if flags:
        cmd = flags + " " + cmd

    print('ENV INFO-------------------------------------')
    os.system('ip a')
    os.system('cat /etc/nccl.conf')
    os.system('cat /opt/amazon/efa_installed_packages')
    os.system('lspci -i efa')
    os.system('cat /opt/amazon/efa_installed_packages')
    os.system('/opt/amazon/efa/bin/fi_info -p efa')
    print('-----------------------------------------')

    print(f'running command "{cmd}"')
    os.system(cmd)
    print('exiting')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    train()
```

train2.py

```
import argparse
import os

import torch
import torch.distributed as dist

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--local_rank', type=int, default=0)
args = parser.parse_args()
print('local_rank', args.local_rank)
dist.init_process_group(backend='nccl')
num_gpus = torch.cuda.device_count()
rank = int(os.environ['RANK'])
print('env rank', rank)
torch.cuda.set_device(rank)
world_size = dist.get_world_size()
rank = dist.get_rank()
print('dist rank', rank)
device = rank
if rank == 0:
    t = torch.tensor(5, dtype=torch.int32, device=f'cuda')
else:
    t = torch.tensor(0, dtype=torch.int32, device=f'cuda')

print(f"{rank=}", f"{t=}")
dist.broadcast(t, src=0)
print(t)
```

launcher I run on local machine

```
import boto3
import sagemaker
from sagemaker.pytorch import PyTorch


sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()
# sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()
iam = boto3.client("iam")
role = iam.get_role(RoleName="Sagemaker_role")["Role"]["Arn"]
print(f"SageMaker Role: {role}")
print(f"Default SageMaker Bucket: {sagemaker_session.default_bucket()}")

estimator = PyTorch(
    entry_point="entrypoint.py",
    source_dir="./config_dir/",
    role=role,
    image_uri=(
        "763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/pytorch-training:1.12.1-gpu-py38-cu113-ubuntu20.04-sagemaker"
    ),
    instance_count=2,
    instance_type="ml.g4dn.12xlarge",
    volume_size=(
        100
    ),
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
    max_run=3600 * 2),
    subnets=[
        "my subnet with nat gateway"
    ],
    security_group_ids=[
        "my security group with permissions to allow connecting the machines"
    ],
    enable_network_isolation=False,
)

print(estimator.get_vpc_config())

estimator.fit()
```

when I run this, I get the output and error:
output on algo-1

```
Invoking script with the following command:
/opt/conda/bin/python3.8 entrypoint.py
2023-01-10 01:01:39,762 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     Exceptions not imported for SageMaker TF as Tensorflow is not installed.
using multi-instance distributed training
nccl_socket_ifname='eth0'
master_addr='algo-1' master_port='7777'
num_gpus=1 hosts=['algo-1', 'algo-2'], curr_host='algo-1' node_index=0 num_hosts=2
ENV INFO-------------------------------------
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 06:dd:fd:68:cd:33 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.200.5.58/24 brd 10.200.5.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
13: veth-pause1@if14: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 7a:1d:6f:77:0e:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 169.254.255.18/28 brd 169.254.255.31 scope global veth-pause1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
NCCL_DEBUG=INFO
NCCL_SOCKET_IFNAME=^docker0
# EFA installer version: 1.15.1
# Debug packages installed: no
# Packages installed:
efa-config_1.9_all efa-profile_1.5_all libfabric-aws-bin_1.14.0amzn1.0_amd64 libfabric-aws-dev_1.14.0amzn1.0_amd64 libfabric1-aws_1.14.0amzn1.0_amd64 openmpi40-aws_4.1.2-1_amd64 ibacm_39.0-1_amd64 ibverbs-providers_39.0-1_amd64 ibverbs-utils_39.0-1_amd64 infiniband-diags_39.0-1_amd64 libibmad-dev_39.0-1_amd64 libibmad5_39.0-1_amd64 libibnetdisc-dev_39.0-1_amd64 libibnetdisc5_39.0-1_amd64 libibumad-dev_39.0-1_amd64 libibumad3_39.0-1_amd64 libibverbs-dev_39.0-1_amd64 libibverbs1_39.0-1_amd64 librdmacm-dev_39.0-1_amd64 librdmacm1_39.0-1_amd64 rdma-core_39.0-1_amd64 rdmacm-utils_39.0-1_amd64
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma]
00:01.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
00:01.3 Non-VGA unclassified device: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 08)
00:03.0 VGA compatible controller: Amazon.com, Inc. Device 1111
00:04.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Amazon.com, Inc. Device 8061
00:05.0 Ethernet controller: Amazon.com, Inc. Elastic Network Adapter (ENA)
00:06.0 Ethernet controller: Amazon.com, Inc. Elastic Network Adapter (ENA)
00:07.0 Ethernet controller: Amazon.com, Inc. Elastic Fabric Adapter (EFA)
00:08.0 Ethernet controller: Amazon.com, Inc. Elastic Network Adapter (ENA)
00:09.0 Ethernet controller: Amazon.com, Inc. Elastic Network Adapter (ENA)
00:1a.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Amazon.com, Inc. Device 8061
00:1b.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU104GL [Tesla T4] (rev a1)
00:1c.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU104GL [Tesla T4] (rev a1)
00:1d.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU104GL [Tesla T4] (rev a1)
00:1e.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU104GL [Tesla T4] (rev a1)
00:1f.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Amazon.com, Inc. NVMe SSD Controller
# EFA installer version: 1.15.1
# Debug packages installed: no
# Packages installed:
efa-config_1.9_all efa-profile_1.5_all libfabric-aws-bin_1.14.0amzn1.0_amd64 libfabric-aws-dev_1.14.0amzn1.0_amd64 libfabric1-aws_1.14.0amzn1.0_amd64 openmpi40-aws_4.1.2-1_amd64 ibacm_39.0-1_amd64 ibverbs-providers_39.0-1_amd64 ibverbs-utils_39.0-1_amd64 infiniband-diags_39.0-1_amd64 libibmad-dev_39.0-1_amd64 libibmad5_39.0-1_amd64 libibnetdisc-dev_39.0-1_amd64 libibnetdisc5_39.0-1_amd64 libibumad-dev_39.0-1_amd64 libibumad3_39.0-1_amd64 libibverbs-dev_39.0-1_amd64 libibverbs1_39.0-1_amd64 librdmacm-dev_39.0-1_amd64 librdmacm1_39.0-1_amd64 rdma-core_39.0-1_amd64 rdmacm-utils_39.0-1_amd64
provider: efa
    fabric: EFA-fe80::491:4ff:fed2:82c9
    domain: rdmap0s7-rdm
    version: 114.10
    type: FI_EP_RDM
    protocol: FI_PROTO_EFA
provider: efa
    fabric: EFA-fe80::491:4ff:fed2:82c9
    domain: rdmap0s7-dgrm
    version: 114.10
    type: FI_EP_DGRAM
    protocol: FI_PROTO_EFA
-----------------------------------------
running command "NCCL_SOCKET_IFNAME=eth0 FI_PROVIDER="efa" FI_HMEM=0 FI_EFA_USE_DEVICE_RDMA=0 NCCL_DEBUG=INFO FI_LOG_LEVEL=warn FI_LOG_PROV=efa PYTHONPATH=/opt/ml/code:/opt/conda/bin:/opt/conda/lib/python38.zip:/opt/conda/lib/python3.8:/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload:/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages:/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/smdebug-1.0.22b20221214-py3.8.egg:/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyinstrument-3.4.2-py3.8.egg:/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyinstrument_cext-0.2.4-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg:/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flash_attn-0.1-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg:/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/einops-0.6.0-py3.8.egg:/nd-mmaction2 python -m torch.distributed.launch               --nnodes=2               --node_rank=0               --master_addr=algo-1               --nproc_per_node=1               --master_port=7777               /opt/ml/code/train2.py"
/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/launch.py:178: FutureWarning: The module torch.distributed.launch is deprecated
and will be removed in future. Use torchrun.
Note that --use_env is set by default in torchrun.
If your script expects `--local_rank` argument to be set, please
change it to read from `os.environ['LOCAL_RANK']` instead. See
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html#launch-utility for
further instructions
  warnings.warn(
```

continued overall output

```
local_rank 0
env rank 1
dist rank 1
local_rank 0
env rank 0
dist rank 0
rank=1 t=tensor(0, device='cuda:1', dtype=torch.int32)
algo-2:161:161 [1] NCCL INFO Bootstrap : Using eth0:10.200.5.143<0>
algo-2:161:161 [1] NCCL INFO NET/Plugin: Failed to find ncclCollNetPlugin_v4 symbol.
algo-2:161:161 [1] NCCL INFO NET/OFI Using aws-ofi-nccl 1.3.0aws
algo-2:161:161 [1] NCCL INFO NET/OFI Setting FI_EFA_FORK_SAFE environment variable to 1
libfabric:161:1673312505:efa:core:rxr_info_to_rxr():506<warn> FI_HMEM capability requires RDMA, which this device does not support.
algo-2:161:161 [1] NCCL INFO NET/OFI Forcing AWS OFI ndev 2
algo-2:161:161 [1] NCCL INFO NET/OFI Selected Provider is efa
algo-2:161:161 [1] NCCL INFO Using network AWS Libfabric
algo-2:161:223 [1] NCCL INFO NET/OFI [1] getCudaPath dev 0 busId 0000:00:1b.0 path /sys/devices/pci0000:00/
algo-2:161:223 [1] NCCL INFO NET/OFI [1] getCudaPath dev 1 busId 0000:00:1c.0 path /sys/devices/pci0000:00
algo-2:161:223 [1] NCCL INFO NET/OFI [1] getCudaPath dev 0 busId 0000:00:1b.0 path /sys/devices/pci0000:00/
algo-2:161:223 [1] NCCL INFO NET/OFI [1] getCudaPath dev 1 busId 0000:00:1c.0 path /sys/devices/pci0000:00
algo-2:161:223 [1] NCCL INFO Trees [0] -1/-1/-1->1->0 [1] 0/-1/-1->1->-1
algo-2:161:223 [1] NCCL INFO Channel 00 : 0[1b0] -> 1[1c0] [receive] via NET/AWS Libfabric/1
algo-2:161:223 [1] NCCL INFO Channel 01 : 0[1b0] -> 1[1c0] [receive] via NET/AWS Libfabric/1
algo-2:161:223 [1] NCCL INFO Channel 00 : 1[1c0] -> 0[1b0] [send] via NET/AWS Libfabric/1
algo-2:161:223 [1] NCCL INFO Channel 01 : 1[1c0] -> 0[1b0] [send] via NET/AWS Libfabric/1
rank=0 t=tensor(5, device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.int32)
algo-1:164:164 [0] NCCL INFO Bootstrap : Using eth0:10.200.5.58<0>
algo-1:164:164 [0] NCCL INFO NET/Plugin: Failed to find ncclCollNetPlugin_v4 symbol.
algo-1:164:164 [0] NCCL INFO NET/OFI Using aws-ofi-nccl 1.3.0aws
algo-1:164:164 [0] NCCL INFO NET/OFI Setting FI_EFA_FORK_SAFE environment variable to 1
libfabric:164:1673312505:efa:core:rxr_info_to_rxr():506<warn> FI_HMEM capability requires RDMA, which this device does not support.
algo-1:164:164 [0] NCCL INFO NET/OFI Forcing AWS OFI ndev 2
algo-1:164:164 [0] NCCL INFO NET/OFI Selected Provider is efa
algo-1:164:164 [0] NCCL INFO Using network AWS Libfabric
NCCL version 2.10.3+cuda11.3
algo-1:164:225 [0] NCCL INFO NET/OFI [0] getCudaPath dev 0 busId 0000:00:1b.0 path /sys/devices/pci0000:00/
algo-1:164:225 [0] NCCL INFO NET/OFI [0] getCudaPath dev 1 busId 0000:00:1c.0 path /sys/devices/pci0000:00
algo-1:164:225 [0] NCCL INFO NET/OFI [0] getCudaPath dev 0 busId 0000:00:1b.0 path /sys/devices/pci0000:00/
algo-1:164:225 [0] NCCL INFO NET/OFI [0] getCudaPath dev 1 busId 0000:00:1c.0 path /sys/devices/pci0000:00
algo-1:164:225 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 00/02 :    0   1
algo-1:164:225 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 01/02 :    0   1
algo-1:164:225 [0] NCCL INFO Trees [0] 1/-1/-1->0->-1 [1] -1/-1/-1->0->1
algo-1:164:225 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 00 : 1[1c0] -> 0[1b0] [receive] via NET/AWS Libfabric/0
algo-1:164:225 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 01 : 1[1c0] -> 0[1b0] [receive] via NET/AWS Libfabric/0
algo-1:164:225 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 00 : 0[1b0] -> 1[1c0] [send] via NET/AWS Libfabric/0
algo-1:164:225 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 01 : 0[1b0] -> 1[1c0] [send] via NET/AWS Libfabric/0
libfabric:161:1673312506:efa:cq:rxr_cq_write_tx_error():243<warn> rxr_cq_write_tx_error: err: 21, prov_err: Unknown error -21 (21)
algo-2:161:223 [1] ofi_process_cq:1033 NCCL WARN NET/OFI Request 0x7f25a0335028 completed with error. RC: 21. Error: unknown error. Completed length: 0, Request: { buffer_index: 255, dev: 1, size: 0, state: CREATED, direction: SEND }
libfabric:164:1673312506:efa:cq:rxr_cq_write_tx_error():243<warn> rxr_cq_write_tx_error: err: 21, prov_err: Unknown error -21 (21)
algo-1:164:225 [0] ofi_process_cq:1033 NCCL WARN NET/OFI Request 0x7f4a6c335028 completed with error. RC: 21. Error: unknown error. Completed length: 0, Request: { buffer_index: 255, dev: 0, size: 0, state: CREATED, direction: SEND }
```

My security group also has a rule which allows all incoming traffic for all protocols and ports if the source has the same security group. There are no outbound rules which restrict traffic flow.

Comment: Can you try initializing the process_group like this by setting additional params.

dist.init_process_group("nccl", rank=global_rank, world_size=args.nodes*args.gpus)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I printed out the global rank and the world size and initialized init_process_group in the way you mentioned and I am getting the same error. I retrieved global rank and world_size from environ['RANK'] and environ['WORLD_SIZE'] as those variables are populated by torch.distributed.launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to have 2 security group rules:

1. inbound rule that allows all traffic from all ports if the source has the same security group as the subnet (I had this already).
2. outbound rule that allows all traffic from all ports if the destination has the same security group as the subnet (I had a rule such as 0.0.0.0 that allowed all traffic but that didn't allow outbound traffic from EFA).

Comment: How did you specifically enable this outbound rule for EFA? Could you elaborate on the steps? Would be helpful.

Comment: I didn't enable it. I added this rule with the params specified in the answer. There was no option that mentioned `EFA` when adding the security group rule. I added the security group rule from the security group tab of the AWS EC2 page.

Comment: I see, thanks for your answer. For some context: I encountered a similar error when trying to run distributed training using EFA across different aws placement groups, so wondering if EFA is known to work across different security groups. In your case, you mean you added an outbound traffic rule in addition to existing inbound rule? Is that what fixed the problem?

Comment: @ParamsRaman Exactly. I didn't have more than 1 security group. In your case, if you have security groups A, B, and C, I'm guessing that you must add an inbound and outbound rule in security group A that allows all traffic if source or dest is B or C. Then the same thing for security group B (rules for SG A and C) and so on.

Comment: Thanks, could you confirm if you were running your multi-node training using EFA (or was it the standard one using TCP protocol)?

Comment: I was using multi-node training using EFA.